# How do I take a printed set and make it into 1 list?

Tags: r, list, loops, while-loop

I have a loop where I am downsampling rasters and then finding the standard deviation of those rasters. My code is

```
    i=0
    while(i<10)
    {


      # Get the Raster + Noise raster
      NewRaster=NoisyRaster(OriginalRaster,NoiseMatrix)

    DownSampledRaster=DownSampleRaster(NewRaster,CellSize,MEAN)

     TheMatrix=as.matrix(DownSampledRaster)
    StandardDev=sd(TheMatrix, na.rm=T)
     print(StandardDev)



    i=i+1 

   }
```

The issue is, when it prints the standard deviation, it looks like this:

```
     [1] number
     [2] number etc.
```

I need to do this for over 100 iterations, and I need to be able to find the mean and standard deviation of those numbers. How can I put those numbers into a vector so I can do that easily?

Comment: `purrr::map` and related functions are very useful for this sort of thing and I'd highly recommend getting to know how to use them. Get your rasters into a list, say `r`. Then you can do `output <- map(r, function(x) cellStats(x, "sd"))`. This gives you a list of standard deviations for the input rasters. You can `unlist()` this if you want the result to be a vector.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to check those out- I am very very new to R, but I will look them up right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried rewriting your code, this is what I came up with:

```
StandardDev = vector(mode = "numeric")
for(i in 1:10) {


  # Get the Raster + Noise raster
  NewRaster=NoisyRaster(OriginalRaster,NoiseMatrix)

  DownSampledRaster=DownSampleRaster(NewRaster,CellSize,MEAN)

  TheMatrix=as.matrix(DownSampledRaster)
  StandardDev[i] = sd(TheMatrix, na.rm=T)

}
```

Comment: I believe it should, as long as you index the vector with `[i]`